# System stability for difference equations depend on eigenvalues

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, recurrence-relations

I have a difference equation in the form Un = AUn-1 and I am wondering how does the stability of the system depend on the eigenvalues of the matrix A?

My question relates to modelling pig (bonhams) growth over time given a set of initial conditions. My sequence of values for the different seasons in 1 1 7 13 55 and so on and so on.

My A matrix looks as follows [1 6 / 1 0] (excuse the poor formatting) therefore my eigenvalues are 3 and -2.

Can anyone please intuitively explain how these values impact the stability of the population.

From my research so far I've ready about how one of the eigenvalues controls the oscillations around steady state but I don't fully get it.

Also how can I find the stable age distribution of this matrix, is it a case of normalising the eigenvector for one of the eigenvalues to 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to the problem

$$
u_n = A u_{n - 1}
$$

is

$$
u_n = A^n u_0 = (V \Lambda V^{-1})^n u_0 = V\Lambda^nV^{-1}u_0
$$

where $V$ is the matrix containing the eigenvectors of $A$ and $\Lambda$ is a diagonal matrix with the eigenvalues of $A$

$$
\Lambda = {\rm diag}(\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \cdots)
$$

Since

$$
\Lambda^n = {\rm diag}(\lambda_1^n,\lambda_2^n,\cdots)
$$

The solution $u_n$ will blow up if there is a $|\lambda_k| > 1$

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, much appreciated. Regarding the lambdaK in the last line of your reply, does this mean any of the possible k eigenvalues for the matrix or does the largest/dominant eigenvalue have to be greater than 1?

Comment: @PigWolf It means if *a* eingenvalue has norm larger than 1 it will make $u$ diverge. It could be any of the possible eigenvalues