# When is the system of recursive equations $y_{n+1} = Ay_n$ stable?

Tags: matrices, systems-of-equations, recursion

Let $y_n = (y_{1n}, y_{2n})^T.$

I'm wondering what the condition on the matrix $A$ is for the recursive system of equations 
$$y_{n+1} = Ay_n$$
to be stable (i.e neither $y_1$ or $y_2$ blows up). Can I express this in eigenvalues somehow?

I'm specially interested in the $2\times 2$ case but maybe it generalizes to higher dimensions.

Comment: See these links: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2257869/system-stability-for-difference-equations-depend-on-eigenvalues and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_difference_equation#Stability_of_the_first-order_case. No component of $\mathbf{y}_n$ will blow up if and only if all eigenvalues of $A$ are less than or equal to $1$ in absolute value.

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth Ah shit, thanks

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth Not quite.  If there is an eigenvalue of absolute value $1$ with greater algebraic than geometric multiplicity, then you still get blow-up.  Consider e.g. $A = \pmatrix{1 & 1\cr 0 & 1\cr}$ where $A^n = \pmatrix{1 & n\cr 0 & 1\cr}$.

Comment: Ah yes, you're right.